# Spectral norm of a tensor

Tags: numpy, image-processing, multidimensional-array, tensor, norm

I want to create a tensor whose spectral norm is less than or equal to one. I wrote some code to do this but I'm not sure if this is actually correct because I'm not sure whether numpy's L2 norm actually calculates the spectral norm. My code:

```
def make_tensor(shape):
Y = np.zeros(shape)
mat = []
for i in range(3):
    matrix = np.random.random_integers(0, 255, (shape[0], shape[1]))
    matrix = matrix/(LA.norm(matrix,2)+np.random.randint(0,255))
    mat.append(matrix)
    Y[:, :, i] = mat[i]
return Y
```

Will `Y` be tensor whose spectral norm is less than or equal to one?